# C Struct to Swift

Tags: c, swift, struct

in c file : have a struct

```
struct CPerson {
  const char* name;
  int age;
};
```

in swift file:

```
extension UnsafePointer where Pointee == Int8 {
  var string : String? {
     return String.init(cString: self)
  }
}
```

I try use c struct:

```
print(CPerson(name: "baby", age: 1).name.string)
//Optional("baby")
```

but :

```
let p = CPerson(name: "angela", age: 1)
print(p.name.string , p.age)
//Optional("") 1
```

why p.name.string == "" ?

I hope that p.name.string == "angela"

thanks.

Comment: Are you required to work with C struct(s)? why just don't implement it using Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a memory management problem. In

```
 let p = CPerson(name: "angela", age: 1)
```

you pass a Swift `String` to a function taking an `UnsafePointer<Int8>`
argument (the Swift equivalent of `const char *`). The compiler inserts
code to create a *temporary*   C string representation and
passes that to the `CPerson` initializer. The `name` field then points
to that temporary C string.

The problem is that this pointer is no longer valid when the
initializer returns. It may point to something else or may be an
invalid pointer.

A `const char *` in C is just a pointer, it does not imply any
ownership or memory management. You would have exactly the same
problem in C if you assign

```
person.name = someString;
```

and leave the scope where `someString` is defined.

So you have to decide who is responsible
to allocate (and free) the C string storage.

One option would be to duplicate the string in Swift and release
the memory when it is no longer needed:

```
let name = strdup("angela")

let p = CPerson.init(name: name, age: 1)
print(p.name.string , p.age) // Optional("angela") 1

free(name)
```

Another option might be to create C functions `CreatePerson()`
and `ReleasePerson()` which allocate and release the storage.